# Create an R statistical report in HTML with pander

Tags: r, pander

I'm programming an statistical report in HTML with R and Sweave, but I can't improve the table format with `xtable`, so seeing the [pander package](https://github.com/daroczig/pander) by daroczig, I think that is enough to satisfy my purposes.

The problem is when I run `Pandoc.brew` function on a brew file nothing happens, the R console remains as doing something but there is not output and I must close the R session to interrupt the process. This happens with [pander example](https://github.com/daroczig/pander/tree/master/inst/examples) files.

I'm running R 2.15.0 and Pandoc 1.5.1.1-5 on Debian 6.0.5 squeeze. I've installed `pander` package as is shown in pander's website.

Any help will be fully appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @daroczig frequents these parts from time to time, so maybe he'll have some ideas.

Comment: IMHO the pretty outdated (2 years old) Pandoc could result this very strange situation. Could you please verify this by running `pandoc` (outside of R) on the [brewed markdown file](http://daroczig.github.com/pander/minimal.md)? E.g. running `pandoc minimal.md -o test.html` in the dir where you downloaded the above file. If that would work OK, there might be some issues while adding custom HTML/CSS/JS stuff in my pandoc call. I am just installing Debian squeeze to test it, but the best thing to do for you right now would be to install an up-to-date version of `pandoc` somehow :(

Comment: I've just installed a bare Debian Squeeze with R 2.15.0 from CRAN and Pandoc 1.5.1.1-5 from the Debian repos and run `Rscript -e "library(pander);Pandoc.brew('minimal.brew', output = 'test', convert='html')"` in bash without any issues. Could you please run `Pandoc.brew` with `open=FALSE` to see if the problem occurs while opening the file?

Comment: I successfully and easily used the 'hwriter' package some years ago for creating reports on html pages.

Comment: I *suspect* this issue was resolved with a [commit about a month ago](https://github.com/daroczig/pander/commit/4a1eae8f2aa2439b690b0593af31a0da583509f1). Could you please affirm this?